# PHP mail()'s Reply-To header breaks mail function

Tags: php, email

I'm writing a code for the mail function of my project and I can't seem to make the `Reply-To` Header work on PHP's `mail()` function.

Initially, this is the whole code that works for me:

```
<?php
    $sendTo = "receipient@mail.com";

    $headers  = 'To: Kristian Acel Gene A. Cua <kristian.cua@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Bcc: Secret Mail Copy <copy@mail.com>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: Sender Mail <no-reply@mail.com>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();


    $mail = mail($sendTo, "Sample Mail [TEST]", "Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet", $headers, "-fmail@mail.com");

    if($mail) {
        echo "<pre>Message Sent !.</pre>";
    } else {
        echo "<pre>Message Sending Failed !.</pre>";
    }
?>
```

The code above executes and returns "Message Sent !." afterwards. now I tried adding a `Reply-To` line to the `$headers` variable.

```
<?php
    $sendTo = "receipient@mail.com";

    $headers  = 'To: Kristian Acel Gene A. Cua <kristian.cua@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Bcc: Secret Mail Copy <copy@mail.com>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: Sender Mail <no-reply@mail.com>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Reply-To: Reply Mail <reply@mail.com>' ."\r\n";
    $headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();


    $mail = mail($sendTo, "Sample Mail [TEST]", "Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet", $headers, "-fmail@mail.com");

    if($mail) {
        echo "<pre>Message Sent !.</pre>";
    } else {
        echo "<pre>Message Sending Failed !.</pre>";
    }
?>
```

Now this code also executes and returns "Message Sent !." output. yet, I do not receive any mails in the receiver's mail nor the Bcc's mail.

I'm stuck as to where I might've got things go wrong. I checked several tutorials, guides, and documentations on the internet and we all have the same `Reply-To` line yet mine is not working.

Comment: There seems to be nothing wrong with your headers. Do you have access to the logs of your mailserver? There might be a message in there that explains why it refuses to send the mail.

Comment: Note that there are some problems with PHP's `mail()` function such as defective error reporting (as you've noticed) and possible security leaks. I recommend you use Swift Mailer of PHPMailer.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider: apparently no, it is because my project is under free hosting on hostinger

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: will try and read some about them. thanks :)